# Magento 2 sample data excel sheet

Tags: magento2, sample-data

I have successfully installed magento 2. I want to import products in csv file related to drinks. If anyone can help to provide an excel sheet with such data, it would be a great help for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sample file is available at the import product section in the admin panel. you can download it from there.

Comment: I would like you to read my requirements again. I want csv type of file with drinks items to import. The normal deploy command will provide shopping related items as products.